# How to add hooks into CRM software

Tags: crm

Not sure how to ask this question since I know very little about CRM software, but assume the following:

1. Joe has a website that offers a service related to customers of various businesses
2. Joe wants to approach companies and convince them to add hooks into their CRM software, so that every time they view an entry for a customer, there is one additional field, which points to information on Joe's website and is related to that customer.

As I understand it, most/all CRM systems have a way to add a new field for each entry in the database. However, for Joe to make it easier for companies to accept his proposal, can he prepare an add-on/script/plugin/etc so that every company with CRM software of a given brand can just run it and the new field gets added, so that Joe doesn't have to work with every company's individual CRM Software installation and tailor his solution to that? (Basically one add-on for companies who use SAP, one add-on for companies which use Oracle, etc)

Or is each company's CRM installation so customized that it is almost impossible to make a generic add-on/script/plugin/etc for all companies who use CRM of a given brand?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no standard. This is one reason why it's a good idea to stick to popular CRMs such as [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/) and [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/). Both have a large selection of add-ons through [AppExchange](http://sites.force.com/appexchange/home) and [SugarExchange](http://www.sugarexchange.com/) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern CRM solutions is based on an SOA approach. Each CRM platform is design to support independent vendor solutions like this. Each CRM uses a different deployment approach and different software development languages. Depending on the language you know, that may help direct you to the first CRM product.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, you want any system to be able to link in to yours and retrieve a link so that people can pull data from your system via the link. If that is the case the best way is to create a Webservice, any CRM program should be able to call the Webservice and get the required data.